# What to put into my Class's Dispose method

Tags: c#, class, dispose

I am writing my own data access layer class for the first time so I would like to wrap it inside a (using) parenthesis but that requires the class to implement Idisposable.

The only thing I put in there is

```
conn.close()
```

is there something else missing that i should be adding there?

class overview:

```
public class DAL : IDisposable
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlTransaction transaction;
    public int Status = 1;
    public DAL()
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
    }
    public void InsertRequest(UserAndRequestInfo UInfo, UserCrops UCrop)
    {            
    }
    public void InsertBGs(BreedingGroups BG)
    {
    }
    public void EndTransaction()
    {
        if (Status == 1)
            transaction.Commit();
        if (Status < 0)
            transaction.Rollback();
    }
    public void EndConnection()
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    void Dispose()
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
```

called from:

```
        using (DAL db = new DAL())
        {
            foreach (var crop in UInfo.UserCropInfo)
            {
                db.InsertRequest(UInfo, crop);
                foreach (BreedingGroups bg in crop.BGs)
                {
                    db.InsertBGs(bg);
                }
                db.EndTransaction();
            }
            db.EndConnection(); <---- //If 'using' is there I'll remove this line
        }
```

Also, in this particular case, wouldn't be just better to call an db.EndConnection() method

Comment: Are you using a finalizer your your DAL class?

Comment: No, not calling the GC if you mean that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: Call `Dispose()` on any disposable variables in your class.

```
void Dispose()
{
    if(cmd != null)
        cmd.Dispose();
    if(transaction != null)
        transaction.Dispose();
    if(conn != null)
        conn.Dispose();
}
```

edit: `conn.Dispose()` will also call `conn.Close()` so you shouldn't need to also call close it if you call dispose.

Comment: Worth noting that if there are no such variables, having an empty `Dispose()` is legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a choich for you, to use the using scope in **InsertRequest** method instead as the following:

```
public class DAL
{
    public void InsertRequest(UserAndRequestInfo UInfo, UserCrops UCrop)
    {   
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open(); 
            SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            SqlTransaction transaction;

            // Start a local transaction.
            transaction = conn.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");

            command.Connection = conn;
            command.Transaction = transaction;

            try
            {
              command.CommandText = "Insert into ...";
              command.ExecuteNonQuery();
              command.CommandText = "Insert into ...";
              command.ExecuteNonQuery();

              // Attempt to commit the transaction.
              transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               // Attempt to roll back the transaction. 
               try
               {
                  transaction.Rollback();
               }
               catch (Exception ex2)
               {
                  Console.WriteLine("Rollback Exception Type: {0}", ex2.GetType());
                  Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message);
               }
            }
        }        
    }
    public void InsertBGs(BreedingGroups BG)
    {

    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to make database connection in Constructure, remove it out. 
And use the same concept to implement **InsertBGs** method.
This is form to call the

```
DAL db = new DAL();
foreach (var crop in UInfo.UserCropInfo)
{
   db.InsertRequest(UInfo, crop);
   foreach (BreedingGroups bg in crop.BGs)
   {
       db.InsertBGs(bg);
   }
}
```